# Slow loading of PDFs in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using a UIWebView to load local PDFs in an app I am writing. Some pdfs (several hundred pages) load very quickly, while ones that were encoded using Adobe Acrobat (screen scrapes from a website) are loading very slowly - they are much smaller in size (generally less than a few mbs) and much shorter. The weird part is they load quickly in the simulator, but take 10-30 seconds on device. Is this some sort of encoding issue?

Answer (score 0):

The simulator doesn't emulate the device's resources. In your case, the simulator has access to much more memory so it can cache more. Your device, on the other hand, is probably having to deal with memory warnings which subsequently means it's keeping less in memory. Less memory means more rendering means more latency.

Comment: I wish this were the case, no memory warnings are being thrown, plus it is only the PDFs that are encoded by Acrobat that are taking so long. Much larger PDFs are loading quickly.